# Function to reverse a string in C - What if is a string literal?

Tags: c, string, string-literals

I have coded the following function that will reverse a String in C:

```
void reverse(char *str) {
        int length = strlen(str) - 1;
        for (int i=0; i < length/2; i++) {
                char tmp = str[i];
                str[i] = str[length - i];
                str[length - i] = tmp;
        } 
}
```

This works if I do this:

```
char a[]="Hello";
reverse(a);
```

But if I call it passing a string literal, such as:

```
char *a = "Hello";
```

It won't work.

So, how would I modify my function so that it can accept string literals and reverse them?

Comment: So, basically I should make the users who call that function know that a string literal can't be passed?

Comment: The real problem is that you shouldn't be referring to string literals with non-`const` pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You better of copying string to some other temp string.

1. Use another `char*` to copy original string. Allocate sufficient memory.
2. Copy sources string to this one. Don't forget to null terminate it.
3. reverse..
4. Dont forget to free this memory after use.

> ```
> char *a1 = "Hello";
> char* copy_a1 = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(a1)+1));
> strncpy(copy_a1, a1, strlen(a1));
> copy_a1[strlen(a1)] = '\0';
> reverse(copy_a1);
> //free memory used.
> ```

Answer (score 4):

You can not do that, string literals are constants in C

Perhaps, you need to copy the string, much like you do it in your first example, where you initialize a char array using a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is C history.

`char *a = "Hello";` should be `const char *a = "Hello";`.  But `const` came in after C was successful so `char *a = "Hello";` was allowed to remain OK syntax.

Had code been `const char *a = "Hello";`, `reverse(a);` would generate a warning (or error).

To modify create something like:

```
char *reverse(char *dest, const char *src);
```